# Haskell: Unsupported operation (Address family not supported by protocol family)

Tags: c, macos, sockets, haskell

I have this piece of code connecting to local graphite (which is actually just `nc -l -p 2023` running on localhost):

```
getCarbonAddr :: Config -> IO SockAddr
getCarbonAddr cfg = do
    let host = (graphiteHost . graphiteConfig) cfg
    let port = (graphitePort . graphiteConfig) cfg
    -- addrInfos <- getAddrInfo (Just defaultHints)
    addrInfos <- getAddrInfo Nothing
                   (Just host)
                   (Just (show port))
    putStrLn $ "addrInfos: " ++ show addrInfos
    c <- case addrInfos of
           (addrInfo : _) -> return (addrAddress addrInfo)
           _ -> unsupportedAddressError host
    return c
  where
    unsupportedAddressError h = ioError $ userError $
      "unsupported address: " ++ h
```

Config values for host and port are "localhost" and 2023 respectively. When I run this on my OS X after upgrade to Yosemite -- I see the following crash:

```
addrInfos: [AddrInfo {addrFlags = [], addrFamily = AF_INET6, addrSocketType = Datagram, addrProtocol = 17, addrAddress = [::1]:2023, addrCanonName = Nothing},AddrInfo {addrFlags = [], addrFamily = AF_INET6, addrSocketType = Stream, addrProtocol = 6, addrAddress = [::1]:2023, addrCanonName = Nothing},AddrInfo {addrFlags = [], addrFamily = AF_INET, addrSocketType = Datagram, addrProtocol = 17, addrAddress = 127.0.0.1:2023, addrCanonName = Nothing},AddrInfo {addrFlags = [], addrFamily = AF_INET, addrSocketType = Stream, addrProtocol = 6, addrAddress = 127.0.0.1:2023, addrCanonName = Nothing},AddrInfo {addrFlags = [], addrFamily = AF_INET6, addrSocketType = Datagram, addrProtocol = 17, addrAddress = [fe80::1%lo0]:2023, addrCanonName = Nothing},AddrInfo {addrFlags = [], addrFamily = AF_INET6, addrSocketType = Stream, addrProtocol = 6, addrAddress = [fe80::1%lo0]:2023, addrCanonName = Nothing}]
LocalJob: connect: unsupported operation (Address family not supported by protocol family)
```

This seemed weird to me, so I decided to run this C program (googled for "getaddrinfo" example, changed hostname and port, added printing of ai_family):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>

#ifndef   NI_MAXHOST
#define   NI_MAXHOST 1025
#endif

int main(void)
{
    struct addrinfo *result;
    struct addrinfo *res;
    int error;

    /* resolve the domain name into a list of addresses */
    error = getaddrinfo("localhost", "2023", NULL, &result);
    if (error != 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "error in getaddrinfo: %s\n", gai_strerror(error));
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    /* loop over all returned results and do inverse lookup */
    for (res = result; res != NULL; res = res->ai_next)
    {
        char hostname[NI_MAXHOST] = "";

        error = getnameinfo(res->ai_addr, res->ai_addrlen, hostname, NI_MAXHOST, NULL, 0, 0);
        if (error != 0)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "error in getnameinfo: %s\n", gai_strerror(error));
            continue;
        }
        if (*hostname != '\0')
            printf("hostname: %s. ai_family: %i\n", hostname, res->ai_family);
    }

    freeaddrinfo(result);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

After launching it, I saw this output:

```
➜  getaddrinfotest  ./main
hostname: localhost. ai_family: 30
hostname: localhost. ai_family: 30
hostname: localhost. ai_family: 2
hostname: localhost. ai_family: 2
hostname: localhost. ai_family: 30
hostname: localhost. ai_family: 30
```

So, the ai_family 30 seems to be a weird thing. As I understand from [socket.h sources](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/socket.h#L141), it is AF_TIPC protocol, which is quite a rare thing I didn't heard of before. I also opened haskell's [packFamily' sources](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/network-2.6.0.2/docs/src/Network-Socket-Types.html#packFamily%27) and was surprise to see it doesn't handle value of 30 there (doesn't know about AF_TIPC).

The questions I have are: what's the best thing to do now? Did I get the problem correctly? Should haskell handle unknown ai family better? // thanks!

UPDATE: I resolved an issue by putting hint to use ipv4:

```
addrInfos <- getAddrInfo (Just (defaultHints { addrFamily=AF_INET }))
               (Just host)
               (Just (show port))
```

but I still wonder how to resolve this issue "the right way".

Comment: The reason you use `AF_*` names instead of numbers is that the numbers aren't the same on every system. The Linux `socket.h` doesn't tell you what 30 means on non-Linux operating systems. Better check the `socket.h` on your own machine. (I predict 30 will be `AF_INET6`)

Comment: @WumpusQ.Wumbley you are correct, thank you! AF_INET6 is 30 in socket.h on my machine.

Comment: @WumpusQ.Wumbley so, in this address to which I try to connect: `AddrInfo {addrFlags = [], addrFamily = AF_INET6, addrSocketType = Datagram, addrProtocol = 17, addrAddress = [::1]:2023, addrCanonName = Nothing}` I see it resolved addrFamily to AF_INET6 correctly then, but I wonder what does addrProtocol 17 mean. The only thing of value 17 I found is `#define AF_ROUTE    17      /* Internal Routing Protocol */`

Comment: @WumpusQ.Wumbley here's socket.h http://paste.ubuntu.com/8704870/

Comment: I only know the C side of this question... but I suspect the 17 is referring to `IPPROTO_UDP`. If you want to use that field of the `getaddrinfo` result, it goes in the third argument to `socket()`. Usually you can put a 0 there because the address family and the socket type (`SOCK_DGRAM`, `SOCK_STREAM`, etc.) are enough to uniquely determine a protocol.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, `getaddrinfo` (and its Haskell binding `getAddrInfo`) returns a linked-list of addrinfo that can contain IPv4 addresses, IPv6 addresses, or a mixture of the two.  Unfortunately, the *sockets* functions do not allow connecting an IPv4 socket to an IPv6 address, so as you iterate through the list of addresses, you need to create a socket of the right type:

```
addrinfos <- getAddrInfo Nothing (Just hostname) (Just (show port))
let first = head addrinfos
sock <- socket (addrFamily first) Stream defaultProtocol
connect sock (addrAddress first)
```

Note how `(addrFamily first)` is passed to the `socket` function, so that the socket is created in the right protocol family.

In real code, you'll want to iterate over the list `addrinfos` and try connecting to all of the addresses returned by `getAddrInfo`.  When you do that, don't forget to close the sockets that fail connecting.

Comment: Thanks @jch. But one thing I don't get is:
> Unfortunately, the sockets functions do not allow connecting an IPv4 socket to an IPv6 address
localhost (and it's address `[::1]` is pretty much AF_INET6 address, so I still don't get why I get an error.

Comment: How did you create the socket?

Comment: thank you! You are correct. It is hardcoded to be ipv4 in the library https://github.com/ocharles/network-carbon/blob/master/src/Network/Carbon/Plaintext.hs#L47